# How to put newlines in JavaScript window.prompt?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put selected text a user can select in a prompt.

```
function copyToClipboard (text) {
    window.prompt ("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
```

The problem with this is that the text may have newlines. In that case, I only see the first line of the text. Is there anyway I can insert newlines or maybe have a custom prompt that allows this? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The new line thing --> `\n`

So what you will do is simply type:

`prompt("Hello world,\nA newline!", [default text]);`

And about the `custom prompt` thing, there is no [such thing](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/timers.html#user-prompts) in [W3C](http://w3.org/TR). However, it does have a [similar thing called the ***Modal Dialog***](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/timers.html#dialogs-implemented-using-separate-documents), which is just a new window containing a website in it.

Answer (score 2):

`window.prompt` won't be capable of doing that, perhaps you should look at a more convenient (and better) approach:

[How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)